# Endomorphism ring of supersingular elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let $E$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over $F_q$ where $q=p^n$, then $\operatorname{End}(E)$ is an order in quaterion algebra, hence a non-commutative ring.

Question: Is there an endomorphism $\psi$ of $E$ such that $\psi$ doesn't commute with Frobenius morphism $\phi_q: x\rightarrow x^q$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iff $\phi_q\not \in \Bbb{Z}$

(The largest subfields of $End(E)\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Q}$ are $2$-dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$-vector spaces and it is a division ring so any element not in $\Bbb{Q}[\phi_q]$ doesn't commute with $\phi_q$)

Try with $E/\Bbb{F}_9:y^2=x^3+x$ then $\phi_9=-3$ (and $\phi_3\approx \sqrt{-3}$ doesn't commute with $i(x,y)=(-x,iy)$)

Comment: Could you please explain how to see $\mathbb{Q}[\phi_q]\subsetneq End(E)\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: In other words, why the $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[\phi_q]$ is less than $4$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}[\phi_q]$ is a subfield it must be smaller than $End(E)\otimes_\Bbb{Z}\Bbb{Q}$.  If $a$ commutes with $\phi_q$ then the same holds for $\Bbb{Q}[\phi_q,a]=\Bbb{Q}[b]$. In general (algebraic) endomorphisms are roots of $X^2-Tr(f)X+\deg(f)$